# How to make sure parent method is always called before child overrides it in a decorator?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

So I have a parent class:

```
class Parent(Object):
    def function(self):
        do_something()
```

And many child classes:

```
class Child1(Parent):
    def function(self):
        do_something_else_1()

class Child2(Parent):
    def function(self):
        do_something_else_2()

...
```

I would like to ensure that the parent `function()` is always called before the children's `function()`, so that every call to `function()` also calls `do_something()` no matter the class. Now, I know I can do something like:

```
class Child1(Parent):
    def function(self):
        super(Child1, self).function()
        do_something_else_1()

class Child2(Parent):
    def function(self):
        super(Child2, self).function()
        do_something_else_2()

...
```

but I would rather not do that for every child class, because these child classes are being generated on the fly, and because these child classes themselves are being extended further. Instead, I would like to do something that looks like

```
class Child1(Parent):
    @call_parent
    def function(self):
        do_something_else_1()

class Child2(Parent):
    @call_parent
    def function(self):
        do_something_else_2()

...
```

And write a decorator to accomplish the same task.

I have two questions:

1. Is this even a good idea? Am I using decorators and function overriding in their intended way?
2. How would I go about writing this decorator?

Comment: How is the one line `@call_parent` better than the one line `super(Class, self).method(...)`, especially given that the latter is more conventional and likely to be more explicit and flexible?

Comment: ... and doesn't add a function call's worth of overhead to the method call?

Comment: I edited it in the post above, but it's because these child classes are being generated on the fly, and because these child classes are also being extended. I don't want to be calling `super(Class, self).method(...)` all the way down the chain.

Comment: @MichaelDong: What's wrong with calling `super(Class, self.).method(...)` all the way down the chain? And why does dynamic generation of classes cause you to prefer the decorator?

Comment: @user2357112: I don't have good reasons. If there's something wrong with the idea of doing it in a decorator, I wouldn't do it. I was asking to see if there was anything wrong with it. But really the reason is that I would have to change the code in which the classes are generated.

Comment: @MichaelDong then do the conventional thing until you find good reasons (which you may never do, in which case no time wasted).

Answer (score 7):

> Is this even a good idea? Am I using decorators and function overriding in their intended way?

This question is complex to answer without knowing the details about your system. 
Just from the abstract example it looks OK, but replacing the explicit and clear `super()` call with something like `@call_parent` is not a good idea.

Everyone knows or can easily find out what `super()` does and decorator will only cause the confusion.

> How would I go about writing this decorator?

Don't write the decorator, instead you can use the [template method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern):

```
class Parent(Object):

    def function(self):
        do_something()
        do_something_in_child()

    def do_something_in_child():
        pass
```

Now in child classes you only override the `do_something_in_child`, the `function` stays only in the `Parent`, so you are sure your `do_something()` is always called.

```
class Child1(Parent):

    def do_something_in_child(self):
        do_something_else_1():

class Child2(Parent):

    def do_something_in_child(self):
        do_something_else_2():

class Child3(Parent):
    # no override here, function() will do the same what it does in Parent
    pass
```

Comment: Yes - be explicit in the code, very clear, very simple. No need for decorators.

Comment: I think this is a good generic answer.

However, my specific use case is that the parent class is an extension of the `unittest` package's `TestCase` class, with its own `test_case()` method called by the test runner. There are many children of the parent `TestCase` class, with their own `test_case()` methods. These children are then dynamically extended. I guess I'd just like to decorate the children and not worry about what happens when they're dynamically extended. Is this not a good idea?

Comment: @MichaelDong Well, I can't say I understand what exactly you are trying to do. For tests, I usually do the general stuff in the parent's class `setUp()` method and then it is be automatically called before each test case. This way you may not need the `test_case` in the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

Im not well versed on Python but you could so something like:

```
# Function in childredn. Overrides parent one.
def function(self):
        # child code
        super().function() #however it is used
        # more child code
```

If that is not plausible, take a look on template method design pattern.

```
# Function in parent. Do not override this one
def function(self):
    # your parent code
    function_do_something()
    # more code if you need it

# function in parent. Children overryde this one
def function_do_something():
...
```

And, you can allways let function_do_something() be void, in order to only execute your father constructor.